# Python Threading module: how to release RAM used

Tags: python, multithreading, ram

I have a script in Python similar to this one:

```
update_freq_sec = 5
    
import threading, os
from datetime import datetime
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

def bot_task():
    t=threading.Time(update_freq_sec,bot_task)
    t.start()

    print('do something example: Last check: ' + datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    clear()
    t.join()

bot_task()
```

Unfortunately it seems that after few hours, the process accumulates something like 7 GB of ram, it seems the processes don't release the ram usage correctly...
How can I flush the RAM after each iteration finishes?

Comment: You have an infinite, recursive threads, that never quit because each waits for next one. You have a memory leak.

Comment: @freakish yes, it's true and it's correct that the loop is infinite... but I'd like that when a run is complete, it flushes the ram of all previous executions... How can I do that?

Comment: You can't, because none of those threads ever exits. None of them ever completes. But each eats memory. You need to entirely modify this design. Like for example: why do you even need threads when this is a simple infinite loop?

Comment: @freakish I needed threads because they allow concurrent usage. How can I stop a thread after finishing an iteration?
Initially it was like you suggested, instead of using threads it was using a simple infinite while with a pause at the end, but in that way, it couldn't do concurrent tasks.

Comment: @freakish initially in the function there was only the #do something part and the task was executed with a simple while infinite loop with a pause

`while True:
    bot_task()
    sleep(update_freq_sec)`

Comment: Yeah, the loop is fine. I'm not sure why you need threads, why you need concurrency, but... if you want it, then you have couple of options: (1) don't join threads - this will allow them to complete, (2) don't spawn new threads recursively: run one function that spawns threads in an infinite loop with sleep. Second option gives you better control, easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: @freakish can you please make an example of how you would code the option 2?

Comment: @freakish I tried your solution #1 and it seems it works!